# Generate a Graph for day activity

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I tried a chart, I want to generate a graph with interval of 1 hour. I have passed the dates in series format, however is not showing properly. Don't know if it's a date issue or a date format issue.

Here's a Fiddle with what I have done:

http://jsfiddle.net/wFpey/29/

This is my highchart highstock code

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },              
        series: series
    });
```

The series data you can get from fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Your time stamps are in seconds; Milliseconds are required.

e.g., this:

```
`1480489019`
```

Should be:

```
`1480489019000`
```

Right now your x axis is displaying correctly according to the data that has been provided.